# Rails creates an illegal join model record on many-to-many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 2 models with many-to-many relation implemented by has_many/belong_to, as follows:

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :author_books
  has_many :books, :through => :author_books, :validate => false
end
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :author_books
  has_many :authors, :through => :author_books, :validate => false
end
class AuthorBook < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author
  belongs_to :book
end
```

The tables were created in the following migration:

```
create_table :books do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.integer :price
end
create_table :authors do |t|
  t.string :name
end
create_table :author_books do |t|
  t.integer :book_id
  t.integer :author_id
  t.integer :percent
end
```

When I execute the following test code:

```
Book.delete_all
Author.delete_all
AuthorBook.delete_all

author1 = Author.create name: 'a1'
author2 = Author.create name: 'a2'

book = Book.new name: 'b', price: 40
book.authors = Author.where("id = #{author1.id} or id = #{author2.id}")
ret = book.save

AuthorBook.all.each do |ab|
  puts "Author id #{ab.id} author #{ab.author_id} book #{ab.book_id}"
end
```

I get the following good output:

```
Author id 1 author 980190963 book 980190963
Author id 2 author 980190964 book 980190963
```

But when I add the following `after_save` to AuthorBook:

```
after_save :f

def f
  self.book.author_books.each do |ab|
    # nothing
  end
end
```

I get the following good output:

```
Author id 1 author 980190963 book 980190963
Author id 2 author 980190964 book
```

And indeed, when I inspect the database I can see that the AuthorBook record contains nil in its book_id field. Any idea why this happens ?